# I am trying to loop through directory and execute command on them

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I have been trying to loop through sub-directory of current folder and convert all odt files into pdf. 
I have executed following code but it seems I am getting caught in for loop every-time. Also i can't convert files inside directory

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in */;
do
   libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf *.odt
done
```

I have tried using find method like this

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in 'find -type f -name '*.odt'';
do
   libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf *.odt
done
```

Comment: i think that the second attemp is good, except that need `$()` and not `;`
`for file in $(find -type f -name "*.odt")` and then you can call `libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf $file`

Comment: @Silver When I am executing the script my terminal is just freezing like its caught in loop cursor keeps blinking. So does libreoffice accept `$file`

Comment: It is an antipattern to combine `for` loop with `find`.
Please try `find -type f -name '*.odt' -print0 | xargs -0 libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf`.

Comment: @tshiono Your command also freezes the terminal. Can you help me understand why this might be happening.

Comment: with my command, try `set -x` for debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always a good thing to start with output to see what is actually going on.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(find -type f -name '*.odt');
do
   echo libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf ${file}
done
```

Copy one line of output and execute manually to see if it works. After that remove the `echo` and actually convert...